# Why do we take $N = mg - mv^2/r$ opposed to $N = mg + mv^2/r$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

[image: HC Verma volume 1 page 112]

So while solving this problem, the solution assumes the normal force to be $$N = mg - mv^2/r$$
But I've learnt that centripetal force isn't any new force and it's an already existing force acting towards the centre.

So shouldn't it be that
$$mg=mv^2/r$$

Why did the question assume it that way?

Or why not
$$N = mg + mv^2/r$$
Since both centripetal and weight are acting in the same direction.

Comment: As others have noted, the centripetal force doesn't  co exist with all of the other forces as a "seperate force", it IS itself, a component of the net force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, "centripetal force isn't any new force and it's an already existing force acting towards the centre." The centripetal force just refers to the component of the net force in the centripetal direction (orthogonal to velocity). Since the speed is constant here, the centripetal force is equal to the net force. Thus, the important thing to note here is that the normal force and gravity act in opposite directions, so a more intuitive way to write the equation might be
$$F_c = \frac{mv^2}{r} = mg-N.$$

Comment: Here we write $mg-N$ instead of $N-mg$ because the car is staying on the ground and not flying away, this implying that weight is greater than the normal force. Am I right? I think we can explain normal force being less with the help of inertia too right?

Comment: Because we are only dealing with non vector forces, we  need to establish a positive direction, We have already established that the centripetal force is positive, which acts in the same direction as mg, so it comes first.

Comment: If we are dealing with Vector forces, then it would be the addition of the vectors, but we are dealing with magnitudes only and thus need to be careful

Comment: @jensenpaull thanks for clearing it out